# What do I need to do to setup phonegap for mobile app programming in android?

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, mobile, cordova

I coded a mobile browser in eclipse from a tutorial, and I want to use phonegap for mobile apps with native functionality in html/css/javascript. Is it the same as jquery? Do I just have to load the main phonegap library in my main javascript file or html file.

I know this is a dumb question but I'm not sure because I see alot of javascript files. I found the main phonegap library file. Is that all I have to load into my main js file to have a working app?

Comment: what code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cordova.exec API in able to communicate between javascript code and android activity. Maybe this link can help you.

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_05_Android_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf

First thing you need to declare your custom plugin in config.xml

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.AndroidApacheCordovaPlugin.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Implementing the plug-in by using Java code

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) 
            throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("sayHello")){
            try {
                String responseText = "Hello world, " + args.getString(0);
                callbackContext.success(responseText);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling a plug-in from JavaScript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```